# Button to insert text in selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need a button that when pressed it inserts a text,let's say:"On" in the selected cell or selected cells, in a specified range A1:C5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

   Intersect(Selection, Range("A1:C5")) = "On"

End Sub
```